# how to reset tauri app camera and mic permission

Tags: electron, desktop-application, webview2, tauri

I was building a video chat desktop application with react and Tauri. When I request a camera and mic stream, it shows a pop-up to allow and I accidentally clicked deny after that I can't get the camera and mic streams even the pop-up is not coming that allow the streams tried restarting the app and deleting the src-Tauri folder but nothing works. I'm asking if there is a way to reset the permission using javascript, can anyone please help me?

```
const defaultConstraint = {
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    };
 export const getLocalPreview = async () => {
   const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(defaultConstraint);
   return stream
  }
```